# ArgoCD multiple files into argocd-rbac-cm configmap data

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Is it possible to pass a csv file to the data of the "argocd-rbac-cm" config map? Since I've deployed argo-cd through gitops (with the official argo-cd helm chart), I would not like to hardcode a large csv file inside the configmap itseld, I'd prefer instead reference a csv file direct from the git repository where the helm chart is located.
And, is it also possible to pass more than one file-like keys?

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  policy.default: role:readonly
  policy.csv: |
    <<< something to have this append many files
    <<< https://gitlab.custom.net/proj_name/-/blob/master/first_policy.csv # URL from the first csv file in the git repository >>
    <<< https://gitlab.custom.net/proj_name/-/blob/master/second_policy.csv # URL from the second csv file in the git repository >>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any external evaluation in a policy.csv would lead to some unpredictable behaviour in cluster and would complicate argocd codebase without obvious gains. That's why this configmap should be set statically before deploying anything

You basically have two options:

1. Correctly set `.server.rbacConfig` as per https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/master/charts/argo-cd/templates/argocd-configs/argocd-rbac-cm.yaml - create your configuration with some bash scripts and assign to a variable, i.e. `RBAC_CONFIG` then pass it in your CI/CD pipeline as `helm upgrade ... --set "server.rbacConfig=$RBAC_CONFIG"`
2. Extend chart with your own template and use `.Files.Get` function to create cm from files that already exists in your repository, see https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/ , with something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
data:
  policy.csv: |-
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "first_policy.csv" "first_policy.csv" }}
        {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```